# Conditionally add values of one column if a neighboring column meets certain criteria?

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs

I have two columns, A and B. A contains string combinations of words ('word1 word2', 'word3', 'word1 word4', etc), and Column B contains a number.

I then have a separate sheet, with Column C, that contains every unique word that appears in column A in the original. What I want to do is add up all Column B values where that Column C word appears in the matching row in A, and put that in Column D.

My problem is that I'm having trouble doing SUMIFs on ranges. I know I can use ISNUMBER(SEARCH()) to figure out if my column C string is contained in the Column A, and I know I can SUMIF Column B based on whether C is searched in A, but I can't apply it in such a way that I get a formula I can apply to the whole column D, since the words in C don't match rows with where that word appears in A. Also, SEARCH() seems to break when I'm searching through an array, I think because it stops being a string so I get type mismatches?

I can clarify as needed, I understand this is a little confusing. Thanks a ton in advance for the help.

Example: Here's Sheet 1. A is string, B is Int

```
     A       |  B 
word1 word2  | 1  
word2 word3  | 5
word4 word1  | 10
```

And Sheet 2.

```
C     |  D
word1 | 11 (because row 1 and row 3 both contain word1)
word2 | 6 (row 1 and row 2 contain word2)
word3 | 5 (only row 2 contains word3)
word4 | 10 (only row 3 contains word4)
```

I'm trying to populate D. SumIf breaks because I can't get it to search through all of column A for the specific word in C and pull out B value only when C is contained within A.

Comment: Some test data and expected outcome would help clarify your problem.

Comment: Yes, please post some test data, and expected output.  Also, in your separate sheet with Col C - say `C1` has `word1`. You want to SUM the numbers in the original sheet, but *only* where `A1` is `word1`?

Comment: Added example data in the body. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIF with Wild cards:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,"*" & C1 & "*",Sheet1!B:B)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example: combinations of words are in `A1:A20`,
random values in `B1:B20` , and list of unique words in `C1:C10.`
Type in **array formula** (
type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=SUM(IF(ISERR(FIND(C1,$A$1:$A$20)),0,SIGN(FIND(C1,$A$1:$A$20))*$B$1:$B$20))
```

in `D1` and drag/copy down.

[image]

**Edit**

It was assumed that one word can not be a part of another,
like `night` and  `knight`, in which case the `FIND(...)` 
should be replaced with

```
FIND(" "&C1&" "," "&$A$1:$A$20&" ")
```

that is the array function in `D1` changes to

```
=SUM(IF(ISERR(FIND(" "&C1&" "," "&$A$1:$A$20&" ")),0,SIGN(FIND(" "&C1&" "," "&$A$1:$A$20&" "))*$B$1:$B$20))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and works perfectly. Thank you.